# Why does this (i = ++i % 3) generate a warning: "may be undefined"?

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = ++i % 3;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it like this:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c -o main
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4: warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined
```

Why does the compiler say `i` may be undefined?

Comment: The *operation* is undefined, not `i` itself. I.e. it's Undefined Behaviour. Don't do it.

Comment: @Paul R why do you think operation is undefined ? ++i increments i to 1 and modulo opeartor 1 with 3 gives 1 as result. doesnt that work ?

Comment: @niko: See my answer and http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html

Comment: @niko: see Fred's answer below and the links in his answer for further explanation of sequence points etc

Comment: I accept this wierdo implementation of compiler and I know its undefined but never found some links. Thanks for your help

Comment: @niko: I'd hardly call gcc a "weirdo implementation". Seems to be pretty well-respected to me, and as far as this issue is concerned it's completely standards compliant.

Comment: @niko - see the latest draft of the C language standard at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf, section 6.5.  Expressions of the type in the OP are explicitly called out as undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the behavior is [undefined](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2 Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
> modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.<sup>72)</sup> Furthermore, the prior value
> shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.<sup>73)</sup>
> ...
> 72) A floating-point status flag is not an object and can be set more than once within an expression.
> 73) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>     i = ++i + 1;
>     a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>     i = i + 1;
>     a[i] = i;
> ```

The expression `i = ++i % 3` attempts to modify the value contained in `i` *twice* before the next sequence point (in this case, the `;` ending the statement), once by evaluating `++i`, and once by evaluating the larger assignment expression.

Now, why would this be a problem?  After all, C# and Java can handle these expressions just fine.

The problem is that, with few exceptions, C doesn't guarantee that operands in an expression are evaluated in any particular order, or that the side effects of an expression will be applied immediately after the expression is evaluated (unlike C# and Java, which do make those guarantees).  For example, the expression `++i` has a *result* (`i` + 1) and a *side effect* (increment the value stored in `i`); however, the side effect can be deferred until the larger expression has been evaluated.  IOW, the following sequence of actions is allowed:

```
    t0 = i + 1
    t1 = t0 % 3
    i = t1
    i = i + 1
```

Oopsie.  Not what we wanted.

This was a deliberate design decision; the idea is that it allows compilers to reorder evaluations in an optimal manner (by taking advantage of a value that's already in a register, say).  The downside is that certain combinations of expressions will have unpredictable results.

Answer (score 11):

Because you are modifying the value of `i` twice without an intervening [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). It's [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 6):

In standardese, it's undefined behaviour because `i` is modified twice without an intervening sequence point.

```
i = ++i % 3;
```

But that's not really the point.  The real point is: **why on earth would anyone write such code?!**

What is the value that you want `i` to have?  If you're assigning a whole new value into `i` with `i = ...`, what effect are you trying to achieve with `++i`?  If this were parallel-universe-C in which code like this actually had meaning, then -- in the best case -- the incremented `i` is immediately replaced with the whole new value assigned.  So why not just  write it as

```
i = (i+1) % 3;
```

which is also correct in C-as-we-know-it.

Comment: +1 for "why on earth would anyone write such code?!"

Comment: +1 for "why on earth would anyone write such code?!" :)